# Cut line of 3d Surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I used matlab to plot a 3D surface for x,y,z where z=f(x,y).
Now, I need to draw a curve (or line) on the surface that represents the surface points for a specific z value.
Can anybody help ?
Thanks

Comment: You want a contour? `contour`?

Comment: Let me know if the duplicate is not answering your question.